# PHP: Incorrect SQL syntax error

Tags: php, sql, where-clause, syntax-error

I have a PHP class that creates a SQL query based on values entered from a form. I'm getting

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. ) )

Here is my code. The problem is occurring around each of the WHERE clauses, (already dealing with SQL injections btw).

```
    if($from != ''){
        $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($from));
    }

    if($to != ''){
        $to   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($to));
    }



    $tsql = "SELECT COUNT(tblBackupArchive.StatusID) AS total, tblBackupArchive.StatusID ".
            "FROM tblBackupArchive INNER JOIN ".
            "tblBackup ON tblBackupArchive.BackupID = tblBackup.BackupID ".
            "GROUP BY tblBackupArchive.StatusID, tblBackup.ClientID ";

    if($from != '' && $to !=''){
        $tsql .=  "WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate BETWEEN '" . $from ."' AND '" . $to . "') ";
    }

    if($from != '' && $to=''){
        $tsql .= " WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate > '" . $from ."') ";
    }

    if($to != '' && $from = ''){
        $tsql .= " WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate < '" . $to ."') ";
    }

    if(isset($bmsid)){
        $tsql .= "HAVING (tblBackup.ClientID = " . $bmsid . ")";
    }
```

I'm terrible with these syntax errors :(

Can someone help me out?

Jonesy

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide the actual query that is generated and is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` clause is coming before your `WHERE` clause which is a problem.  You'll also have to move your `HAVING` clause to appear after your GROUP BY clause.

More information will be available in the documentation.

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

EDIT:

In addition you should should change `$to = ''` to `$to == ''` and $`from = ''` to `$from == ''` in your `if` clauses.

Answer (score 5):

Your `WHERE` clause needs to come before the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can't place a WHERE after a GROUP BY.  You'll need to append your WHERE clauses, and then after all of your WHERE clauses, put the GROUP BY on the query. e.g.

```
$tsql = "SELECT COUNT(tblBackupArchive.StatusID) AS total, tblBackupArchive.StatusID ".
            "FROM tblBackupArchive INNER JOIN ".
            "tblBackup ON tblBackupArchive.BackupID = tblBackup.BackupID ";

    if($from != '' && $to !=''){
        $tsql .=  "WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate BETWEEN '" . $from ."' AND '" . $to . "') ";
    }

    if($from != '' && $to=''){
        $tsql .= " WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate > '" . $from ."') ";
    }

    if($to != '' && $from = ''){
        $tsql .= " WHERE (tblBackupArchive.BackupDate < '" . $to ."') ";
    }

    if(isset($bmsid)){
        $tsql .= "HAVING (tblBackup.ClientID = " . $bmsid . ")";
    }

    $tsql .= " GROUP BY tblBackupArchive.StatusID, tblBackup.ClientID ";
```

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the following

```
$to=''
```

must look like:

```
$to==''
```

This is logic problem not SQL but still will return strange results.

**UPDATE:** KM comment remind me for a colleague that proposed to write the value on the left side and the variable on the right as solutions of this problem. The code would look like:

> $x = '';
>   if(5 = $x){}    // this throw an error
>   if(5 == $x){}   // this returns false

Comment: `if($from != '' && $to=''){` should be `if($from != '' && $to==''){` and `if($to != '' && $from = ''){` should be `if($to != '' && $from== ''){` in php, "=" means assign a value to a variable, while "==" means does equal.  Even though you the code says `if (.... && $to='')` $to is being assigned the value of empty string and not being checked for having a value of empty string.

Comment: It spoils code readability. I know of that practice for ages but never used it myself.